# how to implement and manipulate a many to many relationship in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

Assume that we've three tables

Course - table

```
------------------
 ID | CourseName
------------------
 1  |  C++
 2  |  Java
------------------
```

Teacher - table

```
-----------------------
 ID |   TeacherName
-----------------------
 1  |   Professor 1
 2  |   Professor 2  
-----------------------
```

CourseTeacher - table

```
----------------------------
 ID | CourseID | TeacherID 
----------------------------
 1  |   1      |     1   
 2  |   1      |     2    
 3  |   2      |     1   
 4  |   2      |     2     
----------------------------
```

Now that's what to do as AFAK, but how to select, insert, update, delete records in such a format!

I mean, I'd use a simple "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (..,..,..)" or a simple "SELECT * FROM ..."

but now to retrieve the same single information I've to use some queries that includes the 3 tables somehow (Hint: I already use joins, but still how!!)

A select and insert SQL statement for my case would be very helpful.

I don't use any models and this complicated stuff, I don't know what the use of such a thing!
I'm using SQL Queries in my ADO.NET Objects and everything is working fine so far!

Comment: okie : but what is your question actually ? can you please elaborate more? Do you want to update CourseTeacher table?

Comment: If its working fine, then why change it?

Comment: @Saurabh- I implemented this structure because I first made a design on a paper and I saw that I need two tables (Courses And Teachers) then there was a many-to-many relationship, so I researched and found that I have to create a third table that works as a reference, But I don't know what tables to update if I want to add a new course or a new teacher!

Comment: GvS- I didn't change anything, my requirements at the beginning was easy then It got complicated, in the first it was just simple select, updata, delete queries from one table...then it got more complicated to include retrieving and update more than one table and have relation between those tables!...my question is how to use my many to many relationship in code (to update it or select it)

Comment: a simpler question...I think to insert a new Course name I need to insert into the Course table and the CourseTeacher table, is that right ? and how to write this complicated insert statement?

Comment: To insert a new Course name, why not just insert into the one table?  Unless you have some teachers to associate with that new course, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what your question is ...

Let's assume that your PK in each table is automatically incremented.

To add a course : `INSERT INTO Course VALUES 'My New Course'`
To add a teacher : `INSERT INTO Teacher VALUES 'My New Teacher'`

Tu add an existing Course to an existing Teacher :
In the worst case scenario, meaning that you only know the names of the Teacher and the Course

```
SELECT ID FROM Teacher WHERE NAME = 'My New Teacher' -> id1
SELECT ID FROM Course WHERE NAME = 'My New Course' -> id2
INSERT INTO CourseTeacher(IDCOURSE,IDTEACHER) VALUES (id2,id1)
```

In fact, in your application, when your user selects a Course to add to a Teacher, you should already know what the IDs are, because when you got the list containing them, you certainly have done this :

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM Teacher
SELECT ID, NAME FROM Course.
```

A link which may be useful if what I wrote is not :
http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx

Comment: Here come your first Right Answer =) congrats and Thanks a lot, it wasn't that hard but everything was just overwhelming.

btw, ok sure I deal with my database using the IDs not the names (thanks for the advice though) ..now if you could hlep with a one select statement that selects any course and all it's associated teachers ? that would make life easier indeed!

Comment: Thanks :)

I would try something like that :

SELECT Course.ID AS CourseID, Course.NAME AS CourseName, Teacher.ID AS TeacherId, Teacher.NAME AS TeacherName FROM Course LEFT OUTER JOIN CourseTeacher ON Course.ID = CourseTeacher.IDCourse INNER JOIN Teacher ON CourseTeacher.IDTeacher = Teacher.ID

It will give you all courses and all teachers associated with them.

Not quite sure about the INNER JOIN, but if it doesn't work, replace it with LEFT OUTER JOIN and it will work.

Comment: I'll try that..+1 Thanks for the effort and welcome to stackoverflow =)

Answer (score 1):

it is as simple as for other table.

1 - I assume , you must have code for insert, update , select for course and teacher table. So continue using same methods.

2- but for CourseTeacher table (Junction table) , you must insert in this table when you actually have corrosponding TearcherId and CourseId avaliable in repective tables.

so when you want to add a new record in CourseTeacher table , first ensure respective values of courseid and teacherid presents.

when you wanna update in junction table , use the Id column  to updae

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I just needed some example codes -which was provided by LaGrandMere-

Thanks for your time anyway =)